# Auto update a table on button click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a table in a page. I want to update / reload the table continuously **on a button click** for **every 5 seconds**.

The table gets the values from the query running in the model and I don't want duplicate values to be put in the table again.

I also want to **stop the reloading** of the table on when I click on a another button which is the stop button.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: why would you want to update the table every 5 seconds? I suggest you to bind the update with onkeyup/onchange of the inputs. that way alot less request will be made to the server.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on first button set interval function, which will execute your updating script. And click on other button will clear this interval.

```
// Click on first button
var flag = setInterval(func, 5000);

// Click on second button   
clearInterval(flag);
```

where func is your updating function

Comment: it will, it is not a timeout function

Comment: what should I do If I want to run a query and reload in the table with the a single button

Comment: var func = function () { query(); }; query is your function which runs your query and update table

Comment: So I would write the my mysql statement in the query function.

Comment: so you want to reload the whole page every 5 seconds? because you handle table page on the server?

Comment: No, I don't want to reload the whole I want to reload the table and a want to to run a updated query when i click on the button

Comment: can you explain more detailed how are you doing it or better to put more code into the question

Answer (score 0):

Try that if possible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using bhanu1.Models;
namespace bhanu1.Controllers
{
    public class ranuController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ranu/
        private personEntities1 per = new personEntities1();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(per.sandeep1.ToList());
        }
        //
        // GET: /ranu/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
        //
        // GET: /ranu/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 
        //
        // POST: /ranu/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]sandeep1 san)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                per.AddTosandeep1(san);
                per.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        //
        // GET: /ranu/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
        //
        // POST: /ranu/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        //
        // GET: /ranu/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
        //
        // POST: /ranu/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
           {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```